# Nodejs Buffer.from returns invalid value

Tags: node.js, encoding, base64

`Buffer.from(' ???', 'base64')`

This code returns an empty buffer instead of throwing an error, which is the expected behaviour. What is the correct way of verifying the validity of encoded data and decoding it in nodejs?

Comment: Try to use some Node package for it, [like this](https://github.com/miguelmota/is-base64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be nothing in the [nodejs 12.16 docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding) about an error being thrown if the characters in a given string are not part of the encoding specified.

In fact, a small experiment seems to suggest that `Buffer.from()` simply ignores such characters that do not belong in the encoding.

```
try{
    const str1 = "ai?73";
    const str2 = "ai73";
    const str3 = "??a?i73??";
    const encoded1 = Buffer.from(str1,'base64').toString('base64');
    const encoded2 = Buffer.from(str2,'base64').toString('base64');
    const encoded3 = Buffer.from(str3,'base64').toString('base64');
    console.log(`On base64 encoding ${str1}: ${encoded1}`);
    console.log(`On base64 encoding ${str2}: ${encoded2}`);
    console.log(`On base64 encoding ${str3}: ${encoded3}`);
}catch(e){
    console.error(`ERROR:`,e);
}
```

It yields the following output:

```
On base64 encoding ai?73: ai73
On base64 encoding ai73: ai73
On base64 encoding ??a?i73??: ai73
```

So, your best bet would be to use a package like is-base64, as suggested by user dajnz in the comments.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-base64